# mysql-update table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

How can i update a table if a value from another table. a illustrate is like this

table products

```
product_name | cat_name | id_cat
Item 1       |  sport   |   
Item 2       |  food    |
Item 3       |  fashion |
```

table category

```
id_cat | cat_name  
 1     | sport
 2     | food
 3     | fashion
```

please give me a query or function how to update field id_cat from table product which value from table category?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply join both tables,

```
UPDATE  products a
        INNER JOIN category b
            ON a.cat_name = b.cat_name
SET     a.id_cat = b.id_cat
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e45ba/1)

for faster performance, add an index on column `cat_name` for both tables.